# Know password, but can't type it

Tags: locked-out, sony-xperia, android-11

Xperia 5 II.
No root.
No bootloader is open.
Debug mode is enabled, but ADB requires authorization.

Situation:
There was an error and my phone's theme has changed. I changed the theme back and rebooted the device. I had a password with non-English characters. Now my keyboard does not have these characters, only English. So I know the password, but I can't enter it. Any suggestions on how to change the locale on the keyboard or enter the password there?

UPD:
I don't want to factory reset, because i don't want to lose all photos of my deceased dog :(

Comment: Would it be possible to type the password on a connected USB keyboard?

Comment: Yes, but only in English. Can't change locale :/